# Why the p value of the minimum P value is powerful?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, bootstrap, statistical-power, type-i-and-ii-errors

I am reading a genetics paper: [A Powerful and Adaptive Association Test for Rare Variants](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4125385/). In this paper, there are several hypothesis tests, $H_1, \dotsc, H_r$, and their corresponding p-values, $p_1, \dotsc, p_r$. In order to increase the statistical power, they choose the minimum P-value, denoted by minP. But using minP cannot control type I error, so they use bootstrapping to calculate the p-value of the minP.

I am confused about why calculating the p-value of the minP can control type I error and increase the statistical power. Can anyone help to explain this?

The method is in the page 4-5 in the paper, which is called aSPU.

Comment: This is covered in great detail in the book "Resampling-based multiple testing", published by Wiley-Interscience.

Comment: Thanks, BigBendRegion!